# PHP file force download TXT file, losing the format after download

Tags: php, text, download

I have a formatted TXT file when it is force downloaded using PHP script, it is losing the format, kindly let me know if there is any other way of doing this.

Pl find below download.php script file:

```
<?php

function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
 /*
 This function takes a path to a file to output ($file),  the filename that the browser     will see ($name) and  the MIME type of the file ($mime_type, optional).
 */

 //Check the file premission
 if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);

 /* Figure out the MIME type | Check in array */
 $known_mime_types=array(
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "html" => "text/html",
    "htm" => "text/html",
"exe" => "application/octet-stream",
"zip" => "application/zip",
"doc" => "application/msword",
"xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
"ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
"gif" => "image/gif",
"png" => "image/png",
"jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
"jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
"php" => "text/plain"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
     $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
 if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
    $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
 } else {
    $mime_type="application/force-download";
 };
 };

 //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
 @ob_end_clean();

 // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

 /* The three lines below basically make the
    download non-cacheable */
 header("Cache-control: private");
 header('Pragma: private');
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

 // multipart-download and download resuming support
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
 {
list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
$range=intval($range);
if(!$range_end) {
    $range_end=$size-1;
} else {
    $range_end=intval($range_end);
}

$new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
header("Content-Length: $new_length");
header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
 } else {
$new_length=$size;
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
 }

 /* Will output the file itself */
 $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
 $bytes_send = 0;
 if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
 {
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
fseek($file, $range);

while(!feof($file) &&
    (!connection_aborted()) &&
    ($bytes_send<$new_length)
      )
{
    $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
    print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // can also possible
    flush();
    $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
}
 fclose($file);
 } else
 //If no permissiion
 die('Error - can not open file.');
 //die
die();
}
//Set the time out
set_time_limit(0);

//path to the file
$file_path=$_REQUEST['filename'];


//Call the download function with file path,file name and file type
output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');

?>
```

HTML File:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>


<CENTER> <a href='download.php?filename=testFile.txt'>Download print file </a>     </center><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "losing the format" mean?

Comment: I have a text file where i have added spaces using str_pad(), to print this on a PRINTED Invoice paper. If i download txt file using ftp, it is as is. When I download using this script, it looses the spaces.

Comment: @user1387008 browsers wont interpret a `\n` (Viewing the source your see its what your expecting) you need to choose if you want the user to get a prompt to download the file to save or you can alternately wrap the output in a `<pre>` tag or pass the output through nl2br() function. Really your function is useless if all you want todo is force download of the file

Comment: I donot want to view the text file in browser, i want to download and open in notepad. If i download using ftp, the txt file is fine and all the spaces are intact.

Comment: then change in your `$known_mime_types` array `"txt" => "text/plain",` to `"txt" => "application/force-download",`, simple fix.. tho your problem is the function in general

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have done this change, but still it is the same. It is not working.

Comment: I have similar problem, after downloading file, there are some spaces at the start of text. **HELP!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Mime application/force-download, which is typically expressed as mime application/x-force-download, is typically used in conjunction with PHP code to trigger a download box rather than for displaying content in a Web browser.

For example, if you had a file on your website that you want the user to download rather than view in the Web browser, you could enter the appropriate mime application/force-download code in the file’s header content type field. Note that mime application/force-download is not a registered MIME type. In addition, when used in PHP code, the preferred spelling of mime application/force-download contains the “x-” prefix.

There are other ways to force downloads including using the content-disposition parameter to identify a file as an attachment. Many PHP scripts include mime application/force-download in if/else statements to force downloads of specific file types that are usually displayed in the Web browser such as PDF files and image files.

However, because application/force-download isn’t registered with the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority, it isn’t always recognized by all Web browsers which leads to errors on the computer user’s end.

Comment: sorry your explaination is difficult to understand, can it be more simpler in terms of solution.